# do I need to learn Java before android programming?

Tags: android

Just want to gather all the information I need before I stick my head in android programming.would be nice if I can get little help for start.
thanks

Comment: Yes :) It would help out drastically.

Comment: you definitely need to learn JAVA before android, since the whole thing is JAVA based classes

Comment: I learnt Java while learning Android app development. I.e. I knew only C++ from similar languages and then learnt both at the same time. Just do a quick introductory tutorial about Java and you're good to go.

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial when you're ready for android, a very useful site: http://www.vogella.com/

Answer (score 1):

Yes you would have to know how to use basic Java before doing Android programming. However, you can learn Java by doing Android programming. Here's a link if you want to start Android development itself: [LINK](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html)

I do recommend learning Java beforehand though. It might get tough if they ask you to alter some .xml files and you still haven't figured out how the java files work and stuff like that.

I guess you could follow these steps:

1. Learn the basic variables and such for Java
2. Learn how to use functions (and methods)
3. Learn how to use classes
4. Start using this knowledge to build a basic Android app. (I recommend NOT starting with actual game development if that's what you want)

Comment: thank you guys for the quick response.I am sure that all the information you gave is going to be helpful.I get back to you guys if I got stuck somewhere.thanks again

Comment: No problem! Android development might be daunting but once you get the hang of it it's pretty fun. If you want to use a more visual approach check out [Xamarin Studio](http://xamarin.com/?gclid=CJnx0ozC0bsCFUFd3god7nAALw)

Comment: I know how to use visual basic.i have done a VB project.is it possible to make android application in visual basic 2010?

Comment: No, as far as I know, Visual Basic isn't used to create Android apps. Only Java and C# are available. As far as you mean the actual Visual Basic 2010 software, you need to install Visual Studio or Eclipse to create apps.